# value of variable in file de-increments when incrementing another value of variable

Tags: awk, sed

For some reason when I try to increment MINOR to 1 an HOTFIX is already in set to 1 it gets de-incremented to 0 and MINOR gets incremented to 1. Can someone please let me know why this happens. Also this is being executed in jenkins as a execute shell script. The mode is MAJOR, MINOR, and HOTFIX so I can select one of these modes when I want to build with parameters in jenkins.

```
PREFIX="TIQPROD_"

MAJOR=$(awk -F '=' '$1 == "MAJOR" {print $2}' /tmp/release/release.txt)

MINOR=$(awk -F '=' '$1 == "MINOR" {print $2}' /tmp/release/release.txt)

HOTFIX=$(awk -F '=' '$1 == "HOTFIX" {print $2}' /tmp/release/release.txt)

M="$MODE"

echo "echo $M $PREFIX_$MAJOR.$MINOR.$HOTFIX"

# Increment variable value in text file
if [ $M == "MAJOR" ] 
then
    MAJOR=$((MAJOR + 1))
elif [ $M == "MINOR" ]
then
    MINOR=$((MINOR + 1))
else
     HOTFIX=$((HOTFIX + 1))
fi

# Copy and rename text file with variable values 
cp /tmp/release/release.txt /tmp/release/front_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt 

# Condition on whether the mode is MAJOR, MINOR, HOTFIX increment variable value in text file with new value
if [ $M == "MAJOR" ]
then
    sed -i "s/^MAJOR=.*/MAJOR=${MAJOR}/" /tmp/release/front_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt
elif [ $M == "MINOR" ] 
then
    sed -i "s/^MINOR=.*/MINOR=${MINOR}/" /tmp/release/front_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt
else
    sed -i "s/^HOTFIX=.*/HOTFIX=${HOTFIX}/" /tmp/release/front_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt
fi
```

Comment: `an HOTFIX` "and HOTFIX "? Please post the exact input file content `/tmp/release/release.txt`, please post the output your script is producing and what you want your script to produce. Please post the output from the script. Please post the value of `$MODE` used within the script. Please provide an [MCVE]. Did you try debugging your script with `set -x` or similar? What did it resulted in?

Comment: Unrelated but ITYM `${PREFIX}_`, not `$PREFIX_` (`PREFIX_` is a different variable from `PREFIX`) in your echo statement.

Comment: @KamilCuk the input of /`tmp/release/release.txt` is
`MAJOR=1
MINOR=0
HOTFIX=0
`

A new file will be created when value of `$MODE` is incremented it will look like
`/tmp/release/front-02-03-2020.txt `
`MAJOR=1
MINOR=1
HOTFIX=0
`

Comment: Don't show us file contents in comments, [edit] your question to show them formatted properly.

Comment: @EdMorton Okay, I'm just getting the hang out this platform. So I'll add this to my original question.

Comment: Great, please do that and then delete the "answer" you posted for the benefit of others reading this in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first just fix your script. Try replacing your whole script with this:

```
PREFIX="TIQPROD_"
awk -v mode="$MODE" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $1==mode{$2++} 1' /tmp/release/release.txt > "/tmp/release/front_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt"
```

then tell us if you still have a problem. I left PREFIX in even though you don't use it and I left your shell variables all upper case even though they probably shouldn't be just for ease of of comparison of the 2 scripts.

Based on [your comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60492107/value-of-variable-in-file-de-increments-when-incrementing-another-value-of-varia/60492523?noredirect=1#comment107015954_60492523) it sounds like you're doing this (i.e. repeatedly running your command against the same original file):

```
$ cat foo
17
$ awk '{$0++}1' foo > bar
$ cat bar
18
$ awk '{$0++}1' foo > bar
$ cat bar
18
$ cat foo
17
```

instead of something like this to actually update the original file:

```
$ cat foo
17
$ awk '{$0++}1' foo > bar && cp bar foo
$ cat bar
18
$ awk '{$0++}1' foo > bar && cp bar foo
$ cat bar
19
$ cat foo
19
```

so it's not that any values are being decremented, they're just never being set to the new value in the input file after your tool runs.

To create the new output file and copy its contents back into the original just do:

```
old='/tmp/release/release.txt'
new="/tmp/release/front_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt"
awk -v mode="$MODE" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $1==mode{$2++} 1' "$old" > "$new" && cp "$new" "$old"
```

To keep the original "release.txt" you could do:

```
orig='/tmp/release/release.txt'
curr='/tmp/release/current.txt'
front="/tmp/release/front_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt"
[ -s "$curr" ] || cp "$orig" "$curr"
awk -v mode="$MODE" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $1==mode{$2++} 1' "$curr" > "$front" && cp "$front" "$curr"
```

Comment: so I replace everything in my script with that you suggested and I still run into the same issue. I chose `$MODE` `MINOR` and that incremented, but `$HOTFIX` got de-incremented.
`front_02-03-2020.txt`
`MAJOR=1
MINOR=1
HOTFIX=0
`

Comment: OK, you've GOT to show us what that input file looks like, see my earlier comment under your question. Show us the contents of the input file, then you running the script and then the contents of the output file afterwards because, honestly, what you claim is happening is impossible with the script I posted so either you're misunderstanding something or there's something you're doing that you haven't told us about yet The word is "decremented", btw, not "de-incremented".

Comment: The input file looks exactly like this
`/tmp/release/release.txt`
`MAJOR=1
MINOR=0
HOTFIX=0
`
Now when I change the mode in jenkins to `$MINOR` the new file gets created with the incremented value shown `/tmp/release/front_02-03-2020.txt`
`MAJOR=1
MINOR=1
HOTFIX=0
`
I change the mode in jenkins again to `$HOTFIX` and `/tmp/release/front_02-03-2020.txt` is the file that gets updated and it decrements `$MINOR`
`MAJOR=1
MINOR=0
HOTFIX=1
`

Comment: Not sure how we're disconnecting here but, for the third time - please don't try to show the input/output file contents in a comment, show it in your question where we can see it formatted correctly with newlines, white space, etc. Run these exact commands and copy/paste the contents of your screen into your question, formatted like you did your code: `cat /tmp/release/release.txt; cat /tmp/release/front_02-03-2020.txt; export MODE='MINOR'; your_cmd; cat /tmp/release/front_02-03-2020.txt`. Replace `your_cmd` with your actual command name of course.

Comment: Sure, I have no problem with putting it in my question, but I can assure you there are no newlines or whitespaces.

Comment: Then THAT is your problem. if your input file contains no newlines or whitespace then neither your original script nor mine would work. The script I posted still won't behave as you say it does though so there may be some other problem too. Again, please post....

Comment: Hang on... I just re-read your comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60492107/value-of-variable-in-file-de-increments-when-incrementing-another-value-of-varia/60492523?noredirect=1#comment107015954_60492523. That sounds like you're starting with release.txt, creating release_date_.txt (a different file), and then next time you run your script you're running it on the original release.txt again without ever having updated it with the result of your previous script execution. And then you are surprised when the values in that file are still their original values.

Comment: Yes, release.txt is already created with the values, but when I go to increment any mode I want it to update the release.txt file with the new value and then create front_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt and copy those new values to this new text file. FYI I'm new to bash so I'm still trying to figure out the best way to get this to work.

Comment: OK, I just added how to do that to my answer. You do have newlines in your input file btw.

Comment: That is close to what I want do. The only thing I don't want to do is update the new values back into release.txt. I want it to be kept in the new file and leave release.txt with the original values to know what they originally were before they were incremented.

Comment: Then you can't run your script against release.txt, you have to run it against whatever the most recent file was you generated on your previous run. I updated my answer to show one way of doing that.

Comment: Will this still work if I just want the front_02-03-2020.txt being updated? I asked because I will be doing this for more than one service release.

Comment: If I don't want to use `curr='/tmp/release/current.txt'` and just want `front="/tmp/release/front_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt"`
"$orig" > "$front" && cp "$orig" "$front"

Comment: Then you have to save the last output file name somehow so you can use it as the input file name next time. There are various options including writing it to a file, "find"ing it in a directory, creating/updating a fixed link to it, etc. You should ask a new question specifically about how to do that so you get answers with C&V on the options.